# How do I acquire the right token for a Web API from within an Azure Function App or Javascript?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have a web service which requires authentication before use. When you type in the URL of the Web Service directly in the browser, everything works fine.   However, if you were to try and call this very same service from Javascript, it doesn't work because authentication has yet to happen.

I've tried calling **getAccessTokenAsync**  (this is part of the OfficeJS libray) but ended up getting one of those 1300x errors.  Also, since this call is still in Preview I would like to avoid it.

The code below gets invoked when you enter the URL to the webservice directly in the browser windows.  You're authenticated and everything works fine.

I just don't know how to do the equivalent authentication from within an Azure Function App, or Javascript (from a Web-Add-In)

```
public partial class AuthStartup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        // This part is for web sso so web pages can consume the API without obtaining a token
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/11/17/skipping-the-home-realm-discovery-page-in-azure-ad/
                Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.ProtocolMessage.Whr = "ourcompany.com";// similar effect to domain_hint from client so users never see the "choose account" prompt
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                },

                MetadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:MetadataAddress"],
                Wtrealm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"],
                // this part is needed so that cookie and token auth can coexist
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudiences = new string[] { $"spn:{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]}" }
                }
            });

        // This part is for bearer token authentication
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                },
                MetadataAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:MetadataAddress"],
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: ezG, I am curious to know if you have looked at this sample: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PowerPoint-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET-InsertChart

Comment: @JakobNielsen I did take a look at ADALjs in the past, but not at this particular page.
I'll try it out and get back to you.  Thanks!

Comment: @JakobNielsen  Unfortunately, that sample has switched from ADAL to MSAL.   Our company is currently using ADAL for now.

Comment: I think you can find the ADAL version of the sample, if you look in the repo commit history.

Comment: @JakobNielsen  I went through the sections that were marked as being changed from ADAL to MSAL.  I found lots of c# code, but not JavaScript code demonstrating how to use the ADAL.js library.

Comment: @JakobNielsen:  My guess is that I should pursue this issue in another thread since I probably was not specific as I should have been and I'm clearer on the issue now.

Thank you for the link.  I did get something out of it nevertheless.